# Does an antenna still receive signals without a resonator?

Tags: ac, radio

I want to amplify the signal before separating the frequencies out but I don’t know if the antenna even receives signals without being connected to a resonator. I want to connect the antenna directly to an analog to digital converter to analyze all frequencies mixed together. Is that possible?

Comment: NO your ADC noise input is greater than the signal , which may be in the uV level for each carrier, lookup "RF SDR best practices

Comment: Like Tony said, your un-amplified input signal is going to be way too low for a ADC to process it.  Voltage out of a basic antenna or antenna element is in the micro-volt (uV) range, or lower.  You would need to amplify such a signal by ~ 1 million times (120 dB, if I did my math right)  in order for an ADC to have any chance of converting it properly.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to amplify the signal before separating the frequencies out but
>   I don’t know if the antenna even receives signals without being
>   connected to a resonator.

It does pick up signals without anything connected. An antenna is just an impedance converter from free space (roughly 377 ohms or, put another way, the ratio of electric field to magnetic field strengths are 377:1) to 73 ohms for a dipole (at the right frequency).

> I want to connect the antenna directly to an analog to digital
>   converter to analyze all frequencies mixed together. Is that possible?

It's possible but problematic without a broadband amplifier because an ADC input is fairly noisy compared to the micro volt signal levels produced by a regular antenna. This is why we use tuned circuits - the wealth (if that's the right word) of signals that can be received across a wide range of frequencies needs to be differentiated into the signal we want and that vastly improves signal to noise ratio and means we can amplify the filtered signal without amplifying what we don't want.

Answer (score -1):

Some cheap radios amplify the input signals before an LC circuit selects only one frequency so the input becomes overloaded. My Sony Walkman FM portable radio does that. So it has a local/distant switch for local stations and they are attenuated but then it cannot receive distant stations. Dumb design.